On a blog site, what are the pros and cons to put tags at the top or bottom of each post?
I see tags sometimes near the top of a post, sometimes near the bottom. What are the pros and cons?

This will depend on the intended use of the tags. Generally tags are placed towards the end because it is an extension of the article or blog post. If the user could not find the desired information, he/she may keep looking in the related posts tagged with the same. So tags come after the blog post.
Tags can also be used as index of topics within an article. They may be used right after the blog title to indicate topics covered in the article. They may also be used as links at the same time to scroll to the topic directly. So it serves both to display topics below the fold as well as navigate to a topic directly. To note that this is a secondary navigation pattern and should be limited to a few tags. A large tag cloud at the beginning of a blog post will most likely be ignored by users, or conform to reading the first and the last two.
